# Can you activate/(bring to front) emacs using native elisp? (e.g when working in another program)

Tags: frames

I want to force emacs to be activated, be bought to frond and 'steal' focus in certain circumstances. E.g when I finish a org-Pomodoro or during an important appointment reminder.

Now, I'm looking for a 'native' way to do so, just to reduce external dependencies.
(just Linux is ok for me, cross-platform would be better).

Is this technically possible from inside emacs?

## [edit] Solution:

If using the GUI, this works well:

```
(x-focus-frame nil)
```

## [For historical reasons...] I have tried:

### Frame visibility (doesn't work)

```
(make-frame-visible)
```

And also:

```
(make-frame-invisible)
(make-frame-visible)
```

But these seem to only work if Emacs is already activated.

### Frame raising (doesn't work)

Lowering frame seems to actually hide emacs.

```
(lower-frame)
```

But raising the frame from a timer doesn't. I.e, nothing happens.

```
(raise-frame)
```

It seems there is a missing 'activate-emacs' before raising it.

### [NOTE on external solution]

Currently, as a (workaround/solution?) I use a bit of elisp:

```
(call-process "activateEmacs")
```

And the respective bash script: (you may need to install xdotool on your system first)

```
#!/bin/sh 
sleep 0.5
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class emacs windowactivate
```

Comment: Try `raise-frame`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestiong. lowering the frame works, but raising the frame doesn't re-raise it for some reason?

Comment: I believe @TomTromey is correct.  You can test as follows.  First, create an idle timer: `(defvar my-timer (run-with-idle-timer 5 t (lambda () (raise-frame))))`.  Suspend the frame with `M-x (suspend-frame)`.  In 5 seconds, that frame will reappear.

Comment: Well, it works if you `(suspend-frame)` and wait there without clicking into another window. But if you suspend the frame and go work in another application, then emacs doesn't re-appear. At least not on my system (fedora 21 with Mate desktop). A simple example is this: `: (run-at-time "5 sec" nil '(lambda () (interactive) (message "trying to raise frame") (raise-frame)))` run this and alt-tab onto another application. The message will appear in the buffer but emacs doesn't get raised... Thoughts?

Comment: I did notice that on my system some windows don't activate properly, e.g opening a link opens it in chrome but chrome isn't bought to the foreground. If the above 100% works for you, it could be just my system...

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev: when I do it and then open a terminal window, the raised frame reclaims focus (using fedora with openbox).

Comment: I'm using the Gui version of emacs? (not the terminal version), were you using the gui also?

Comment: How about taking a look at the code used for `select-frame-set-input-focus` and see if anything in there looks like it might be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using a Window System, you might be able to use `x-focus-frame`.

Note:

- `x-focus-frame` works for Windows as well as for Linux
- prior to Emacs 23.1, use `w32-focus-frame` on Windows.

Comment: yes indeed. (x-focus-frame nil) raises the emacs window. Neat!

Comment: Works on mac too.

Answer (score 4):

Either `(x-focus-frame nil)` or `(other-frame 0)` will do it. I'm not sure if there is any difference in behavior between the two.