# Avy - Moving Between Terminal Frames

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs, avy

I've only just recently started using `avy` to navigate inside my buffers and it seems to work nicely.

As for my question however, with `avy-all-windows` set to `all-frames` I am able to navigate between several *GUI* `emacsclients`. I am also able to move *from* terminal `emacsclients` *to* GUI clients.

However, I am not able to move from one terminal to another, or from GUI clients to terminal clients. The appropriate destination hints do appear in the Emacs frames however, and typing the hint-keys will activates the correct `point` position in the intended destination (terminal) frame but focus will remain in the frame that issued the command.

Is there any way to work around this and change focus to the destination
terminal frame?

Comment: In the meanwhile, `tmux` might be a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Emacs bug. Avy does call `select-frame-set-input-focus` on the proper frame, but that function does not work well on terminal frames.

If you want this fixed, please follow up with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug`.

[see also](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/can-you-activate-bring-to-front-emacs-using-native-elisp-e-g-when-working-in)